# Two urns with balls

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> We consider two urns that contain blue balls and red balls. Urn $1$ has $9$ blue balls and $1$ red one. Urn $2$ has $8$ blue balls and $2$ red ones. We now draw one ball from each urn.
>
> (1) Find the probability of at least one ball being red.
>
> (2) Find the probability of exactly one ball being red.
>
> (3) You know know that exactly one of the balls drawn is red. Find the probability that the ball comes from Urn $1$.

(1) ($\dfrac{1}{10} \cdot \dfrac{2}{10}) + (\dfrac{1}{10} \cdot \dfrac{8}{10}) + (\dfrac{9}{10} \cdot \dfrac{2}{10}) = 0.28$.

(2) $(\dfrac{1}{10} \cdot \dfrac{8}{10}) + (\dfrac{9}{10} \cdot \dfrac{2}{10}) = 0.26.$

(3) Let $R$ be the event of drawing exactly one red ball ($P(R) = 0.26$) and $U_1$ the event of drawing from Urn $1$.

$$P ( U_1| R) = ?$$

---

How are we supposed to find $P(U_1)$? I tried to model the question using a (single) tree diagram but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I think you're thinking about Bayes' theorem when you say "how to find $P(U_1)$", but you don't need that here. Just the definition of conditional probability is needed.$$P(U_1|R)=\frac{P(U_1\cap R)}{P(R)}=\frac{\textrm{prob of picking red ball when urn 1 is chosen}}{\textrm{prob of picking exactly one red ball}}$$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Indeed. This clears things up, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$\frac {1}{10}\times\frac{8}{10}+\frac {9}{10}\times\frac{2}{10}+\frac {1}{10}\times\frac{2}{10}=1-\frac {9}{10}\times\frac{8}{10}$$
2. $$\frac {1}{10}\times\frac{8}{10}+\frac {9}{10}\times\frac{2}{10}$$
3. $$P( U_1| R)=\frac {P(U_1\cap R)} {P(R)}= \frac{\frac {1}{10}\times\frac{8}{10}}{\frac {1}{10}\times\frac{8}{10}+\frac {9}{10}\times\frac{2}{10}}$$